# JSON, jQuery, $.getJSON: JSON Building Confusion

Tags: javascript, json

I always get confused on how to properly format json. I think its because I need to walk away and take a breather.

I have a have a ecommerce system and I have a script that I want to display category information via json. Will displaying it this way:

```
{
    "cat_name": "All Items",
    "cat_desc": "<div><img src=\"item.gif\" /></div>",
    "cat_desc2": "",
    "cat_id": "756",
    "cat_father_id": "0",
    "cat_image": "",
    "per_ship": "0.00",
    "item_ship": "0.00",
    "item_int_ship": 0,
    "per_int_ship": "0.00",
    "noProducts": "45",
    "disp_order": "3",
    "cat_img_folder": ""
}
```

Would I be able to reference these items after being initlized to an object like so:

```
obj.cat_name
obj.cat_id
```

Comment: What you have is a json *object* (which is also a javascript object), but not a json *string*. I don't understand which one of the two you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's properly formated, if your service returns that information you could do the following

```
$.getJSON('YOURSERVICEURL', function(data) {

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    console.log('KEY: ', key, ' VALUE', val );
  });

});
```

where key will be the property and val the value when you access it (in the fashion data[key] === value, or, data.key === value). 
So, yes, if `data` has the key that you're looking for (in your case `cat_name cat_id`, you can get them.

One thing to have in mind is that Numbers doesn't need to be between `""`, if you want them to be numbers when you access them via object properties

Also, if you ever need to know if you're formatting your json correctly you could take a look at [this link](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply... yes, but you have to know that those properties are in the object for sure or you'll get some strangeness.

You can also access them via:

```
obj[cat_name]
obj[cat_id]
```

of:

```
var x;
for(x in obj){
  console.log("x:" +x+" - value:"+obj[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you run eval or the proper json2 parse function you can access it like you said, and if you ever have issues read the syntax at www.json.org, also there's a site called http://www.jsonlint.com where you can paste your JSON in and test it.

You'll find there's a lot of freedom in JSON, u can have nested objects/arrays and more